# How to get the selected displayed string in a dblookupcombobox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I am using Delphi XE 6 with MySQL and FireDAC.

I have a CUSTOMER table with a column GENDER.

The customer record has a gender M.

In the form, I use a dblookupcombobox to let the user to select from a REF_GENDER table.  The table has a column GENDER (with data 'M' or 'F') and a column DESC (with data 'Male' or 'Female').  I also created a calculated field with data [ M - Male ] and [ F - Female ].

The dblookupcombobox will display the calculated field for user to selected.  Then, the 'M' or 'F' will then be updated to the CUSTOMER table.

Now, my question is how to get back the string [ M - Male ] ?  I just want to get back this string for printing so that the printed version is similar to the display form.

Comment: Have you simply tried `TDBLookupComboBox.Text`?

Comment: Thanks Uwe Raabe, TDBLookupComboBox.Text is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just access the lookup table/query itself - it should be synced with the value in the dropdown.